# Get REST API documented in single JSON using Swagger

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

I have a `Java` +`JAX-RS` + `Jeresy` environment and successfully integrated `Swagger`.
Everything works dynamically and json files are created per resource.

Is there a way to extract all of the JSON representations into a single file so I could share it with others in offline? 
I am looking for a single file JSON that I can then read using Swagger-UI.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger 1.2 doesn't support a single-file structure. That was changed in Swagger 2.0. So as long as you're with Swagger 1.2, you'd have the share the set of files.

Comment: well I am using swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10 and its latest version is 1.3.10 that doesn't support Swagger2.0

Comment: That is correct. You can use the 1.5 SNAPSHOT version to produce a Swagger 2.0 spec, but bear in mind it is still under development.